Method Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn::lineClamp does not exist
hey im using laravel filament and i got this error

Method Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn::lineClamp does not exist.

can anyone help? im pretty sure that lineClamp method is exist in my filament version.
and all other methods from TextColumn are working well.
here is my composer.json
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "filament/filament": "3.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },

and here is my MenuResources.php
public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('nama')->label('Name')->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('deskripsi')->lineClamp(1)->label('Description'),
                TextColumn::make('category.name')->label('Category')->badge()->color('gray')->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('harga')->money('IDR')->label('Price')->sortable(),
                TextColumn::make('stock')->label('Stock')->sortable(),
                ImageColumn::make('foto')->disk('public_folder')->label('Photo'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()])
            ->bulkActions([Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make()])]);
    }

I also have tried updating the composer, but the problem still persist

A good practice will be to remove and reinstall filament. also try to run php artisan optimize:clear

Someone just upgrade to fixed this problem, try see:
https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/7122
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/upgrade-guide#badgecolumnenum-removed
